# forEach object Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to do a `forEach` but it's saying that's is undefined somewhy,

this is my code :

```
var array: MoneyDTO[] = prices

array.forEach(function (money: MoneyDTO) {
                if (money.currency == 'QTW') {
                    //Do stuff
                }
});
```

But it says that .currency is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your array contains `MoneyDTO` that is undefined or has undefined `currencty` property. Its self explainatory.

Check it with `console.log(array)`

Comment: I tried `console.log(array[2].currency)` and it prints ok, seems like this `forEach()` is not working fine

Comment: print `array` not `array[2]`, edit your question and include output. Foreach forks fine, your code/data is broken.

Comment: array is returining to me 9 objects, by the way if I do something like money.currency.otherValue = price it will create this new otherValue?

Comment: And at least one of them is broken. Did you include console output like I told you to?

Comment: I know where the bug is.... I'm using this. inside this function and it's saying that is undefined, how do I avoid this undefined? using fat arrow? Can you post an example to how to move this function to a fat arrow function to avoid this undefined when I use this.?

Comment: Paste related code to the question. I see no `this` in whatever you have posted in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171565/discussion-between-stuartdto-and-antoniossss).